# Shift/Unshift element of an array in buffer

Tags: arrays, emacs, elisp

It would be nice if one could move an element of an array (left/right) in when editing source code. For instance, if you have this array (in any language)

```
var a = ['foo', 'bar', baz]; // JavaScript for instance
```

and if the cursor is next to `baz` (at the beginning, at the end, or even in the middle) you would be able to move that element within the array (in this case it is the last one so you can't move it to the right), if you run a function `move-array-item-left` or `unshift-array-item` it will move `baz` to the left:

```
var a = ['foo', baz, 'bar']; // JavaScript for instance
```

Does anybody know how to implement this kind of feature (or maybe someone has already done that)?

It would be nice to have this for [web-mode](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode), but maybe there is a general minor mode that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position the point at the beginning of `baz` and hit <kbd>C-M-t</kbd>.  That runs the command `transpose-sexps`, which seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something like this for the Lisp family of languages.
See [the gif](https://raw.github.com/abo-abo/lispy/master/doc/screencast-5.gif).

It's possible to do something similar for the Algol family as well.

Comment: Side question, how did you create those gifs? Was it created in linux, win or OSX?

Comment: Linux, savemydesktop+mplayer+imagemagick+makefile to tie it together. And finally GIMP to crop and set delay between frames.